# Applet loads again in jQuery tabs when collapsible is true

Tags: jquery, html

I add IRC Chat applet in jQuery tabs. And when switching tabs, Applet loads again in all browsers except Firefox.

Code i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.sortable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var xOpts =
   {
      event: 'click',
      collapsible: true
   };
   $("#x").tabs(xOpts);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="x" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:auto;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#x-chat"><span>Chat</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#x-rules"><span>Pravila</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#x-test"><span>Test</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div style="height:93%;overflow:auto;padding:0;" id="x-chat">
<div id="lightIRC" style="height:100%; width:100%; text-align:center;">
  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("/virtual/x-serv.us/htdocs/chat/lightIRC.swf", "lightIRC", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "/virtual/x-serv.us/htdocs/chat/expressInstall.swf", params);
 </script>
</div>
<div style="height:100%;overflow:auto;padding:0;" id="x-rules">
<div id="wb_Text1">
<span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px;"><strong>P</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px;"><strong>ravilnik &amp; Uslovi </strong></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px;"><strong>X</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px;"><strong>-Serv Mreže</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><br><br>Korišćenjem </span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Aria
l;font-size:13px;"><strong>X</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">-Serv mreže obavezujete se na poštovanje navedenih pravila i uslova. Administracija mreže zadržava puno pravo da u bilo kom momentu bez obrazloženja diskonektuje korisnika i zabrani mu pristup mreži kao i linkovanom serveru. <br>Na mrežu ulazite na sopstvenu odgovornost i rizik. IRC </span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>X</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;
font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">-Serv mreža ne snosi nikakvu odgovornost za bilo kakvu informaciju poslatu od strane korisnika, osim u slučaju administracije mreže. <br>Na korisniku je apsolutna odgovornost da izoluje softver ili informaciju, izvrši antikontaminaciju i preduzme potrebne korake kako bi sprečio softver ili informaciju da mu, ukoliko su zaraženi ili inficirani, oštete informaciju ili sistem. <br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>X</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">-Serv mreža ne daje nikakve garancije po pitanju podobnosti informacije isporučene ili primljene na mreži, ili njom, za bilo koju svrhu, niti po pitanju njene autentičnosti, zakonitosti,punovažnosti, tačnosti, ispravnosti, pouzdanosti, kvaliteta,postojanosti, kompletnosti ili aktuelnosti. <br>Svaku takvu informaciju u potpunosti obezbeđuju i za nju odgovaraju korisnici mreže.<br><br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13
px;"><strong>1.</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"> Striktno se zabranjuju Troll servisi:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; Spam, Flad, Proksi, Phishing,<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; Botnet, Klonovi, DDOS, Scam.<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; Kao i sve ostale nelegalne stvari<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; koje su kaznjive zakonom o <br>&nbsp;&nbsp; &quot;visoko tehnoloshkom kriminalu&quot; Republike Srbije.<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; Svi logovi šalju se nadleznim organima na proveru.<br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>2.</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"> Zloupotreba i širenje ličnih podataka korisnika.<br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>3. </strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">IRC Trojanci, Skripte i Linkovi za kradju ličnih podataka.<br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>4.</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"> Širenje bilo kakve pornografije,vrbovanje maloletnih lica.<br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>5. </strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Dozvoljeno na privatnom kanalu:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; Jedan EggDrop, Bouncer (psyBNC, ZNC, SBNC)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; Dva localhost klona sa 1 ip adrese,<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; Sve iznad ovoga bice na K ili G liniji.<br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>6.</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"> Bezpotrebno zadržavanje na kanalu #Help.<br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>7.</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"> Uznemiravanje &amp; prozivanje:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; nacionalno, versko i seksualno<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; fizičkoj ili psihičkoj bolesti (nedostatku ili anomaliji).<br><br></span><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><strong>Važno:</strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><br>Ako ste uznemiravani sa nekim od zabranjenih pravila<br>možete nam se obratiti kanalu #help.<br>ili koristiti komandu za ignorisanje:<br>/ignore nick ili /ignore *!*@host.<br>Takođe možete sebi dodati posebne modove:<br>-&gt; +D (primer: /mode Nick +D)<br>- zaključava vaš pvt i privatna obaveštenja svim korisnicima.<br>-&gt; +R (primer: /mode Nick +R)<br>- zaključava vaš pvt samo neregistrovan
im korisnicima.</span>
</div>
</div>
<div style="height:510px;overflow:auto;padding:0;" id="x-test">
```

You can see my DEMO here -=> http://x-serv.us/index2.html

TNX for HELP :)

Comment: By "applet", do you mean a Java applet, or something else? Because I don't see any `<applet>` tag here.

Comment: This seems strange since the `object` exists whether or not it's visible.

Comment: Perhaps it reacts to `display:none`. Can you force `visibility:hidden` instead?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Where i can use this?
Probably you dont understand me, when i changing tabs, and i go back to first tab, flash applet with irc loads again. They not keep loaded. WHY? How to make applet loaded, not to loads all time when changing tabs?

Comment: The flash applet is reloaded but the corresponding `<object>` DOM node is present even if the flash applet apparently isn't.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeees :) What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to place it out side of the tabs , then move it off the page when you don't need it using a click function. Then when you need it just move it to the place you want it on the page with something like absolute positioning. I don't know if this is a good practice but it worked for me with google maps.